# I am stuck at practice python exercise 4

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
number = int(raw_input("Enter a number :"))
div = range(0, number)
list = []
while div <= number:
    if number % div == 0: 
        list.append(div)
        div =+ 1

    print list
```

this is my code which I made for this exercise :
 http://www.practicepython.org/exercise/2014/02/26/04-divisors.html
 I am new to programming so i dont know what is wrong with my code but its not giving any output.

Comment: `div` is a list, not a number... Try to use `for i in range(0, number):` instead of your while statement.

Comment: So it can be done only using for loop ?

Comment: or start with `div = 0` and keep your `while` loop

Comment: when learning to program, especially a language with implicit (inferred) typed variables, always pay attention to how your variables are defined and their type. In your question, you defined `div` as a `list` (that's what `range(0, number)` is) and `list` as a list (you should not use `list` as a variable name by the way), so things like `div < number` don't make much sense. When variable don't behave as expected, always ask yourself: how is this variable defined in the first place?

Comment: @AkshayArora: The task gives a strong hint to use a `for` loop.

Comment: @dirkgroten thanks buddy as I m new into programming so it's quite confusing for me but I m learning :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this answer is simple enough, and looking from the down-votes people think this too. However... one only learns by asking!

There are three essential mistakes in the code that you propose, and a number of ways to make it more Pythonic.

1. First, and foremost, dividing by zero is not possible! So you'd want to check numbers in the range (1-`number`).
2. Based on the indentation `list` is printed many times, instead of only at the end of completing the `while` loop.
3. You want to avoid using `list` as a variable because it is a Python keyword.

Then, to make it more Pythonic my proposition is the following:

```
number = int(input("Enter a number :"))
output = []

for i in range(1,number+1):
  if not number%i:
    output.append(i)

print(output)
```

Note that `raw_input` no longer exists in Python 3.x. Also note that this way we avoid the `while` loop, that from experience, can easily lead to mistakes. In stead it has been replaced by automatically looping through the entries in the list generated by `range(1,number)`.

Finally a note on `range` but probably also on semantics. I consider `number` also to be a divisor of `number`. To do so I have used `range(1,number+1)`. Because, for example `range(5)` returns a list up to `5`: `[0,1,2,3,4]`. I.e. it does not include `5`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code you need:

```
number = int(input("Enter a number :"))
list = []
# theoretically this is the limit you should test for divisors
for div in range(2, int(number/2 + 1)):
    if number % div == 0:
        # adds the divisor to the list
        list.append(div)
        div += 1

# prints all divisors in new line
for item in list:
    print(item)
```

If you are using python 2.7, instead of `input` use `raw_input`

Comment: Why the `range(2, int(number/2 + 1))`. I thought the exercise was to find all numbers 1..`number` that are dividers of `number`?

Comment: @TomdeGeus: It's a shortcut that would work if `number` itself wouldn't be needed in the list. Still there are other flaws in the code: `div +=1` is not needed and overwriting the builtin `list` by defining a variable with the same name is bad style.